# Sequelize validation errors on findAll

Tags: node.js, validation, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize 2. I am basically trying to make a validation that only allows at most 2 folks with a role equal to member per account.  Currently, I get an error:

Unhandled rejection Error: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

when I run a dev db build.  Incidentally, there are 8 records I try to insert.

How should I change this validation to get it to work without this error?  I'm new to node.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var MemberAccount = sequelize.define('member_account', {
role: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    isIn: {
      args: [['member',
              'advocate']],
      msg: 'Must be member or advocate'
    },
    hasFewMembers(value, next) {
      var self = this;
      var v = MemberAccount.findAll({
        where: {
          role: 'member'
        }
        ,attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('role'))]]
      })
      .then(function(member_count) {
          if (self.role=='member' && member_count == 2) {
            throw new Error('Only 2 members allowed per account!');
          }
          return next();
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
         return next(err);
      });

      return v;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel a hook is more justified for your use case than a validate.
You can create a "beforeCreate" hook which will fire before inserting records in DB.
See this link http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html

Comment: thanks. so you are saying just put my hasFewMembers function in a hook. beforeCreate.  Great.  However, I think my error has a different root cause and is caused by how I structure the hasFewMembers function and how I call the database.